# 2 Tables - Query them with one another and store pk's from each table into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

So lets say I have TABLE1 and TABLE2.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
first_id int NOT NULL,
first_random_attribute varchar(255)
primary key(first_id)
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(
second_id int NOT NULL,
second_random_attribute varchar(255)
primary key(second_id)
)
```

How would a compare TABLE1 and TABLE2 with one another, create a relational table, check if their x_random_attribute's are equivalent and if they are, store the primary keys of each one in the new relational table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portable SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Whatever (
  first_id int NOT NULL,
  second_id int NOT NULL,
  common_random_attribute varchar(255)
  );

INSERT Whatever (first_id, second_id, common_random_attribute)
SELECT
    t1.first_id, t2.second_id, t1.first_random_attribute
FROM
    TABLE1 t1
    JOIN
    TABLE2 t2 ON t1.first_random_attribute = t2.second_random_attribute;
```

Specific alternatives:

- MySQL allows you to `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` in one statement
- SQL Server/Sybase have `SELECT .. INTO ...`

Comment: since I am doing this in MySQL, I could do:

     CREATE TABLE Whatever( 
     first_id int NOT NULL,
     second_id int NOT NULL,
     common_random_attribute varchar(255)
     ) 
     AS SELECT...(what you put above?)

Comment: @BackpackOnHead: no `CREATE TABLE Whatever AS SELECT... `. AFAIK you can't specify columns/types etc when you use a SELECT

Comment: I tried it as the way I wrote it (in this reply) and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RealatedTable(
   first_id int NOT NULL,
   second_id int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO RealatedTable(first_id,second_id)
SELECT 
   TABLE1.first_id,
   TABLE2.second_id 
FROM 
   TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 
   ON TABLE1.first_random_attribute=second_random_attribute
```